# How would you call async method in a method which cannot be async in C# without using .Result

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core

I am overriding a method, HandleRequirementAsync, so I can't modify the return type of that method.  However, I am calling a method in UserManager which is async and requires an await so I had to put this code in another method.

```
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
          AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
          EducationArmRequirement requirement)
        {

            if (!IsEducationGroup(context).Result)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }


            context.Succeed(requirement);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        protected async Task<bool> IsEducationGroup(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
        {
            var userId = context.User.Identity.Name;
            ApplicationUser u = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userId);
            if (u.Group == 3 || u.Group == 4)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
```

The code above seems to work in testing but it uses .Result to unwrap the Task to get the bool.  I have seen several places that say be careful of using result.  I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c) which tries to explain why but I am not getting it.

I can't put an await in the HandleRequirementAsync method to allow this to unrap normally because then I would have to modify the return type which I can't do for this overridden method.

Am I approaching this the correct way in using the .Result or am I going to come across some issues here and if so what is another way to approach this which would work?

Any help/explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: just define method as `protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync`. There's no return type change here and you can use `await`

Comment: Also no need in `return await Task.FromResult(true);` just go with `return true;`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks for the note.  I tried that initially but it complained about Task as a return type and wanted Task<Task> with this error:  Since 'EducationArmHandler.HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext, EducationArmRequirement)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'? Then when changed to Task<Task> it doesn't agree with the overridden methods type so it says no overload with that type.

Comment: Have a look at answer below from @Charles Mager - that's what I'm talking about

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, the async modifier doesn't change the method signature - you can just add this.  You can also simplify to remove usage of `Task.FromResult` in both methods:

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    EducationArmRequirement requirement)
{
    if (await IsEducationGroup(context))
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}

protected async Task<bool> IsEducationGroup(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
{
    var userId = context.User.Identity.Name;

    ApplicationUser u = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userId);

    return u.Group == 3 || u.Group == 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The key I was missing was the await in the if statement.  I did try that at one point but apparently I had issues elsewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with .NET Core 3.1. Adding the `async` keyword expects another return type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

IsEducationGroup group function

```
protected async Task<bool> IsEducationGroup(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
{ 
await Task.Run((){

            var userId = context.User.Identity.Name;
            ApplicationUser u = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userId);
            if (u.Group == 3 || u.Group == 4)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    })
```

HandleRequirementAsync function

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
          AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
          EducationArmRequirement requirement)
        {

           var result =  await (!IsEducationGroup(context));
            if(!result)
                return;


            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }
```